# Flink web ui authentication using nginx

Tags: nginx, apache-flink, nginx-config

I'm trying to add authentication to the web dashboard using `nginx`. Flink's `rest.port` is set to `8081`, connection to this port is disabled by firewall. I'm using `nginx` to listen to requests on port 8080 and redirect to port 8081 them with username/password authentication (Port 8080 is open).

This is what the server block looks like in `nginx.conf`.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:8081;
        auth_basic           "Administrator's Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

The port redirection is working fine but there are a couple of issues. When I go to the inactive job manager's UI, redirection to the active job manager is not happening. And when I try submitting a job from the UI, the upload gets stuck at "Saving".

[image: Job upload stuck at "Saving"]

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
location / {
    auth_basic           "Administrator's Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;

    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

you need to using proxy_set_header ...., it's included in proxy_params, ing /etc/nginx,